# Why inner element width doesn't increase when dynamic content is added to outer container

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add dynamic content to `.innerright`. Why doesn't the width of `.a` increase dynamically. What should I do it to make sure `.a` takes width of `.innerright` container dynamically. I use javascript code to add the content dynamically.

```js
var list = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  list = list + i + 's';
}

$('.innerright').append(list);
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.innerleft {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.innerright {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.a {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class='innerleft'>

  </div>
  <div class='innerright'>
    <div class="a">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should it increase?

Comment: I think because the i have not set the width so it is taking up 100% width so   when the outer div width increases ".a" should take up the width of outer div.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you set a calculated width on the container element and specifically tell the container to deal with overflowing content by adding a scroll bar.

As far the css is concerned the element is always at it's calculated width and the extra content just expands into the overflow area rather than affecting the container's width.

I'm not sure this is fixable in css alone while maintaining the overflow property to scroll. Everything is doing as it should, the elements are taking the widths they should take and that is being maintained throughout dynamic content editing - overflow is not part of width.

You could use the javascript `scrollWidth` value and use that to dynamically edit the width of the `.a` element.

See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/romqdzxb/)

The important bit is:

```
$('.a').width($('.innerright')[0].scrollWidth);
```

which gets the scroll width of the `.innerright` element, that includes the width and the overflow and uses that to set the width of the `.a` element, which also now goes into the overflow area.

And of course, you'll need to call and recall this after you add any dynamic content!

NB, the `[0]` means get the first element in the array of DOM nodes returned by the JQuery call.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, block elements don't grow, they overflow. You're CSS makes that overflow scrollable. In order to acheive your goal, wrap the content (`<a>` and text) in an inline-block element, which will grow, and now you're `<a>` will receive it's parent (grown) width, and the `<div>` will still have scrollable overflow:

```js
var list = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  list = list + i + 's';
}

$('.contentspan').append(list);
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.innerleft {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.innerright {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.a {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.contentspan {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class='innerleft'>

  </div>
  <div class='innerright'>
    <span class='contentspan'>
      <div class="a">

      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, this has nothing to do with dynamic content or JS. If the text was inlined in the HTML you'd get the exact same results.